# how to read array from json settings file in net 6

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

i need to read this section from web api project in net 6

```json
{
  "ProductsMigration": {
    "Products": [
        {
            "Product": 
            {
            "SourceAppId": 4215,
            "TargetAppId": 6218
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've created this class:

```cs
internal class ProductMigration
{
    internal class ProductMigrationItem
    {
        public string SourceAppId { get; private set; }

        public string TargetAppId { get; private set; }
    }
    public ProductMigrationItem Product { get; set; }

}
```

this the code to read the setting:

```
var items = _Configuration.GetSection("ProductsMigration:Products").Get<ProductMigration[]>();
```

items.count is 1 but SourceAppId and TargetAppId are null.

Comment: which .NET-language is this?

Comment: c# net 6.0 web api application

Comment: Then I'm adding the [tag:c#-6.0] tag. Hope that's right.

Comment: Why are your setters marked as private? What's supposed to be setting them?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, that's not right. .NET and C# versions aren't interchangeable. C# 6 came out nearly a decade ago, .NET 6 is a year or so old. If you don't know the specific version number or it's irrelevant (like in this question) then just use the language tag itself, without a verison.

Comment: now it works. i removed private. thanks.

Comment: @mason ah! Thanks for correcting this then :) That's why I asked! As you can tell, I'm as far as can be from C#/.NET.